# How to maintain speed of scroll after decreasing it and how to remove elements from DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this little animation which is a game. When spamming divs have crossed the bottom of window, the scroll bar appears and it moves down from top by 50px every 200 miliseconds.The speed of animation is set at 2000 and each time decrease by 100 in this interval. I want it to remain at (let's say 200) when it reach it.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5416zdx2/1/

My html code:

```
<h1 id="score" style="position:fixed; margin-left: 30px">0</h1>
<div id="container" style="width: 34%; height: 100%; background-color: white;margin:0 auto;">
<span class="point" style="display:none"></span>
<p id="over"style="left:40%; font-size:4vw; top:50%; margin-top:-50px;position:fixed; display:none"><b>Game Over</b></p>
</div>
```

The jquery code:

```
var i = 0, blackPosition, running = false;;
var speed= 2000;
$(document).on('click', function() {
    if(running) {
        return;
    }
    running = true;
    var time = setInterval(function() {
        if(i % 4 == 0) {
            blackPosition = Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
        }
        var math = (blackPosition == (i % 4)) ? 0 : 1;
        $("span").first().clone().addClass("rectangle_"+ math).clone().fadeIn().appendTo("#container").on('mousedown',function(){
        if(math < 1){
         $('#score').html(function(x, val) { return val*1+1 });
         $(this).addClass("color").unbind("mousedown");
         }else if(math = 1){
         $("#over").css("display","initial");
         $("span").css("background-color","gray");
         clearInterval(time)
         }else if(speed = 200){
         speed = 200}
         });
        i++;
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:"+=50px"},speed-=100,'linear')
    }, 200);
});
```

And also, I'm looking for a method to remove the elements from body when they are not visible from top.

Comment: what do you mean by " I want it to remain at (let's say 200) when it reach it." ?

Comment: when the speed reaches 200, I want to remain constant from that moment.